# Fields copy between records in one table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, copy, rows

The products table contains records with two language versions. How to copy the products_description (language id = 2) field to a product with the same product_id (language_id = 3) with one query? Temporarily, the records must be identical.

[image]

Comment: Post your current attempt and what database engine are you using - MySQL Server (`mysql` tag) or SQL Server (`sql-server` tag)?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to copy the product description from one product to one with the same product id. The thing I don't get is the fact that you said that it's a multi language table. In this case there is no use to copy the product description, because it has to be translated. Incase it doesn't have to be translated, it wouldn't be a smart move to just copy the same data in a table. You will just end up with duplicate data in your database. In this case I would recomend creating a reference table, wich makes use of the product id as an index to your products